# Xamarin, VS 2017 Community - error when updating NuGet packages

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am creating new App (Cross-Platform App - Xamarin-Forms; Blank app for Android and IOS; ) and after that, I am going to manage NuGet Packages -> Update where are some packages in the update section. After selecting one or all (it does not matter which) and click update there is that error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'App5.Android'.            0

I am using `Xamarin Forms` with `Visual Studio 2017 Community`.
Clearing ``NuGet Cache` does not help.

Comment: This was most likely caused by a package that is no longer available from the nuget source you use. If you try again you should be able to see which packages are missing or what went wrong in the NuGet package restore log.

Comment: Now I am getting another error `Access to the path 'Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll' is denied.`. And this is for all packages, just the path is different depends on the package. I am using VS2017 as admin.

Comment: Clean your project solution, delete the bin and obj file, restart VS and try again.